# Am I creating my raygeneration shader correctly

Tags: raytracing, directx12

Hi I want to create a ray generation shader which traces rays inside a box frustum given by an Orthographic projection matrix(XMMatrixOrthographicLH) I use the following ray generation shader code:

```
struct RTConstants
{

    matrix invproj;
};

struct Simpleraypayload
{
    float3 outcol;
};
RWTexture2D<float4> outtex: register(u0);
RaytracingAccelerationStructure basicas:register(t0);
ConstantBuffer<RTConstants> rtconsts:register(b0);
[shader("raygeneration")]
void rgsmain()
{
Simpleraypayload payload;
payload.outcol=float3(0.0f,0.0f,0.0f);
RayDesc ray;


ray.TMin=0.001f;
ray.TMax=10.0f;
ray.Direction=float3(0.0f,0.0f,-1.0f);
    uint3 rayidx=DispatchRaysIndex();
    uint3 raydims=DispatchRaysDimensions();
    float2 clippointxy=rayidx.xy/float2(raydims.xy);
    clippointxy=(clippointxy*2.0f)-float2(1.0f,1.0f);
    float4 clippointnear=float4(clippointxy,0.0f,1.0f);
    clippointnear=mul(rtconsts.invproj,clippointnear);clippointnear=clippointnear/clippointnear.w;
    float4 clippointfar=float4(clippointxy,1.0f,1.0f);
    clippointfar=mul(rtconsts.invproj,clippointfar);clippointfar=clippointfar/clippointfar.w;
    ray.Origin=clippointnear.xyz;
    ray.Direction=normalize(clippointfar.xyz-clippointnear.xyz);
    TraceRay(basicas,RAY_FLAG_NONE,0xFF,0,0,0,ray,payload);
    //flipping the output.
    uint2 outindex=uint2(rayidx.x,raydims.y-rayidx.y);
    
    outtex[outindex]=float4(payload.outcol,1.0f);
}
```

here "invproj" is the inverse of the ortho projection matrix for which we are trying to shootrays for.Am I right in using this rgs shader code for tracing all possible rays inside the frustum represented by the ortho matrix whose inverse I am using here?I have tested it for ortho projection only though.

Answer (score 0):

Yes the raygen shader used here is correct for shooting rays inside the frustum given by the projection matrix(whose inverse is used here).